# query ldap for groups a user belongs to

Tags: clojure, ldap

im using clj-ldap.client.get

where I have tried various variations for user-query, but not knowing the ldap language and not being able to find anything good at explaining it.

I have tried

```
"cn=<username> , cn=User, dc=google, dc=co, dc=uk"
```

so far this has only returned

```
"googlesecretq": "25",
  "authpassword;orclcommonpwd": "<password>",
  "uid": "<username>",
  "mail": "<username>@google.co.uk",
  "dn": "cn=<username>, cn=Users, dc=google, dc=co, dc=uk",
  "objectclass": [
    <objects that mean nothing to me>
  ],
  "sn": "<username>",
  "userpassword": "<password>",
  "cn": "<username>",
  "givenname": "<username>"
```

so anyone tell me where to learn the ldap language, or even better what query I need to run to get the groups/roles for a given user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LDAP, a lot depends on what schema objects are installed and some depends on what decisions were made by whomever setup/configured the system. There isn't one single standard. For example, the LDAP I work with using clj-ldap uses cn=,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com and groups are in cn=Groups,dn-exmple,dn-com.  Some of the schemas, such as the posix or nis schemas have fairly clear definitions regarding how to define groups, but often people define their own schema objects as well.  Knowing what schema objects the server users can certainly help narrow down possible candidates.

You either need to talk to one of the admins for the ldap server your querying to find out what schema objects it has or perhaps use a tool like ldapsearch to explore the various containers/trees. The exploration approach has the limitation that your search user (who you are binding as to perform the search) may not have sufficient access rights to query all objects/trees/containers.

The documentation which comes with ldapsearch (available on most Linux systems) is pretty good at explaining how the ldap search syntax works. It is a bit 'clunky' and seems odd at first, but is actually pretty straight-forward - looking at the exmaples in the ldapsearch docs and man pages will help.

The openLDAP documentation has some good info, thought it isn't presented that well and can be hard to find things. Keep in mind that there are a number of different types of LDAP with different features and conventions. Knowing which type your working with might also help.

Comment: Thanks Tim x, I think ours is users and then the groups have the users listed within them. Im guessing I would have to query all groups to find out which groups a perticular user is in, does this sound right?

Comment: Depending on your structure, you will probably be able to either query for all members of a specific group or query to see what group someone is a member off. The ldapsearch syntax is what you use for clj-ldap and so you should be able to work out the basic format of your search using ldapsearch and then translate that to clojure. However, you do need to know for certain what the structure is to format that query.